Linear Combinations of Sample Mean Difference
What is the standard error of the mean difference between 2 variables (a & b)? I have the following data:
$$
\sigma_{A} = 1.813529 \nonumber \\
\sigma_{B} = 1.932183 \nonumber \\
cov(A,B) = 2.6222222 \nonumber \\
n = 10 \nonumber \\
\nonumber \\
$$
I want to find what is the standard error of the mean difference ie $$se(\bar{B} - \bar{A})$$
I originally used the following method where
$$
\sqrt{var(\bar{B} - \bar{A})} = \sqrt{var(\bar{B}) + var(\bar{A}) + 2(1)(-1)\cdot cov(\bar{A},\bar{B})} \nonumber \\
 \qquad\quad\ \  = \sqrt{var(\bar{B}) + var(\bar{A}) + -2\cdot \frac{1}{n} \cdot cov(A,B)} \nonumber \\
  = \sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{A}}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{\sigma_{B}}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{2}{n}\cdot cov(A,B)}
$$
However the answer wasn't right, is there something wrong with my method?
For the part on covariance for sample means, I used the following link

I would have thought $\sqrt{var(\bar{B}) + var(\bar{A}) + -2\cdot \frac{1}{n} \cdot cov(A,B)}$ $= \sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2_{A}}{{n}} + \frac{\sigma^2_{B}}{n} - \frac{2}{n}\cdot cov(A,B)}$ rather than $\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{A}}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{\sigma_{B}}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{2}{n}\cdot cov(A,B)}$
